# SqlDataReader hangs on Dispose()

Tags: c#, .net, sqldatareader

I use the following approach to execute queries over database and read data:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Connection string"))
{
    connection.Open();

    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TableName", connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
              // read and process data somehow (possible source of exceptions)
        } // <- reader hangs here if exception occurs
    } 
}
```

While reading and processing data some exceptions can occur. The problem is when exception is thrown `DataReader` hangs on `Close()` call. Do you have any ideas why??? And how to solve this issue in a proper way? The problem has gone when I wrote `try..catch..finally` block instead of `using` and called `command.Cancel()` before disposing the reader in `finally`.

Working version:

```
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Connection string"))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TableName", connection))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                // read and process data somehow (possible source of exceptions)
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // handle exception somehow
            }
            finally
            {
               command.Cancel(); // !!!
               reader.Dispose();
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Is this also happening outside the debugger?

Comment: using block would automatically close and dispose!You don't have to close it within using block..Also show us your code within using block

Comment: What the whole thing in an `try/catch` block tell what the exception is. If you don't tell us what the exception is, we cannot help.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey This is happening outside the debugger, that's why I had to use a debugger.

Comment: @BlackFrog Well, exception is not corresponding to database interaction, any kind of Exception. I throw exceptions myself. The only fact that if ANY exception happens - reader hangs.

Comment: What happens if no exceptions are thrown? What if you remove all the code in the inner block except for the raw `reader.Read()` calls and maybe other calls directly and simply that reference `reader`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders If no exceptions are thrown everything works great. Exceptions are generated, for example, because of some incorrect values in config files, etc...

Comment: And, if you just replace the inner code with `throw new Exception("Help!");` then it hangs?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes. But it is worth to notice that query itself returns large number of rows.

Comment: whats the longest you have waited for it to return?  could it possible be cleaning something up since it is returning so many records?...

Comment: Are you sure it hung getting your large amount of row? Can you process atleast one row after the `SqlDataReader.Read` method?

Comment: @BlackFrog It hangs on its Close()/closing bracket of using body as I can see stepping through the code. I can read rows, only if exception happens I got troubles disposing the reader.

Comment: How long does it take for you to simply do `while (reader.Read()) ;`? Are you sure this is a hang and not a timeout?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I am sure, I think answer by usr makes sense a lot.

Comment: @QuéPadre: try it and let us know how it works for you.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Already tried, I just wanted to know the reason of this "strange" behavior.

Comment: @QuéPadre: you tried, and, did it work?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes. My workaround is totally working.

Comment: @QuéPadre: great! If one of the answers helped you, then you should accept it (check the check mark).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When an exception occurs you stop processing data before all data is received. You can reproduce this issue even without exceptions if you abort processing after a few rows.

When the command or reader is disposed, the query is still running on the server. ADO.NET just reads all remaining rows and result sets like mad and throws them away. It does that because the server is sending them and the protocol requires receiving them.

Calling `SqlCommand.Cancel` sends an "attention" to SQL Server causing the query to truly abort. It is the same thing as pressing the cancel button in SSMS.

To summarize, this issue occurs whenever you stop processing rows although many more rows are inbound. Your workaround (calling `SqlCommand.Cancel`) is the correct solution.

Comment: Move the SqlCommand.Cancel to the catch block to prevent the hang effect. Finally maybe called after all records are read from the server side. Moving the code to the catch block may save some processing time!

Comment: In my case SqlCommand.Cancel() is not working. still it is taking too much time to close the DataReader

Comment: @HaiderAliWajihi there recently were multiple .NET bugs around this. I know of them because I follow the corefx repo on GitHub. Try upgrading to the latest version although I think it does not contain all the fixes.

Comment: This is crazy. I just ran into this in 2018, where Dispose() was taking more than two seconds to run. Why would anyone want it to read all remaining rows behind the scenes if you're disposing the reader anyway?

Comment: @flodin the protocol requires all rows to be read. One could argue that Dispose should send a Cancel command, though.

Answer (score 3):

About the `Dispose` method of the `SqlDataReader`, MSDN ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) has this to say:

> Releases the resources used by the DbDataReader and **calls Close**.

Emphasis added by me. And if you then go look at the `Close` method ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close.aspx)), it states this:

> The Close method fills in the values for output parameters, return
>   values and RecordsAffected, increasing the time that it takes to close
>   a SqlDataReader that was used to process a large or complex query.
>   When the return values and the number of records affected by a query
>   are not significant, the time that it takes to close the SqlDataReader
>   can be reduced by calling the Cancel method of the associated
>   SqlCommand object before calling the Close method.

So if you need to stop iterating through the reader, it's best to cancel the command first just like your working version is doing.

Answer (score -2):

I would not format it that way.
Open(); is not in a try block and it can throw an exception
ExecuteReader(); is not in a try block and it can throw an exception
I like reader.Close - cause that is what I see in MSDN samples
And I catch SQLexception as they have numbers (like for timeout)

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
SqlDataReader reader = null;
try
{
    connection.Open();  // you are missing this as a possible source of exceptions
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TableName", connection);
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();  // you are missing this as a possible source of exceptions
    // read and process data somehow (possible source of exceptions)
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle exception somehow
}
finally
{
    if (reader != null) reader.Close();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I deliberately put a simplified version of code which I got from msdn example, just to reproduce my issue.

Comment: Then what is the question?  This is what I consider a proper way.  This is not the same as what you consider proper.  As I pointed out your code is not catching an exception on Open or ExecuteReader.

Comment: The question is "Why does the reader hang without calling command.Cancel() explicitly"? I don't think this is a normal behavior.

Comment: So your question is you have no exception handling and you wonder why it hangs on an exception.  That is what happens when you have an unhandled exception.  How do you conclude it is hanging on Close?

Comment: excuse me, but when an exception occurs disposing of the reader is taking place, and in that very moment the program hangs! Exactly at the moment of closing the reader.

Comment: But you state both Close and Dispose.  How to you determine what } is?  And furthermore where do you care?  Why would you not have exception handling on a database?

Comment: } is Dispose() which in turn calls Close() =) I care because my program just hangs, that's really stupid.

Comment: So you are seeing that in the call stack?  I cannot make it fail on }.  Just a comment.  This is not to argue.  But why would not have exception handling in your program?  A database could be down.  As you said you could have bad config settings.

Comment: my program is covered with try.. catches, and I think I will use your format as well, but... in the question discussed I couldn't even get into catch block, because program stuck... I changed using to try..catch so I could see where the program hangs.